# how to reuse if checks in python

Tags: python

i try to execute the commands as as little as possible or re-use the code

```
id = 12345
state, result = commands.getstatusoutput('command -where "(fieldid eq ' + id + ') and (fieldname eq male)"')
if state != 0:
        print "error"
        newstate, newcom =  commands.getstatusoutput('command -where "(fieldid eq ' + id + ') and (fieldType like child)"')
        if newstate != 0:
           print "need to create male child"
        else:
            anotherstate, anothercom = commands.getstatusoutput('command -where "(fieldid eq ' + id + ') and (fieldType like child)" -get FatherId')
            master = anothercom.split(' = ')[1]
            masterid = re.findall(r'\d{5}', master)[0]
            # this will return the fathers ID and now i wanna check if the father has a male child, here i would go back up at the first row and enter into the if statements again but now with this new id, but i dont know what to use to do that
            # state, result = commands.getstatusoutput('command -where "(fieldid eq ' + masterid + ') and (fieldname eq male)"')
            # if state != 0:
            #     print "error"
            #     newstate, newcom =  commands.getstatusoutput('command -where "(fieldid eq ' + masterid + ') and (fieldType like child)"')
            #     if fwstate != 0:
            #         print "need to create male child"

    else:
        print "male child exists"
```

i commented out the block that i would like to replace, dont know how or with what (make some reference to the first like to get back there but with another variable, masterid)

use for loop? or define two functions?

maybe also this diagram would help...
http://s22.postimg.org/ufy89kzyp/python.jpg

Comment: where's fwstate coming from? You may create a function and call it with id as parameter

Comment: Recursion comes to my mind but unfortunately I can't explain more in depth right now

Comment: i corrected parts of the code ... but more importanly i added a link to a diagram, which exaplins what i want to do... and i dont know how to code it exactly... anyone?